# How to loop through Alamorefire data response in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use alamofire for the first time in my project. I'm a little confused how to loop through my data response though and store my result in an array.

I have a data model to capture the data which contains 2 attributes (name, description).

```
import Foundation

class categoryModel {
    var name: String?
    var description: String?

    init(name: String?, description: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    } 
}
```

I then have a TableViewController which creates an array of categoryModel type. In my viewDidLoad I then make a call to my API and capture some data. This is the part I'm struggling with. I want to store the response values in the array.

```
var categories = [categoryModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

Alamofire.request("http://my.custom.api.url", encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            //print(response)

            if let json = response.result.value {

            }


    }
}
```

I have printed the response object and get the following:

```
SUCCESS: (
    {
        "category_number" = 4;
        description = "";
        name = "Traditional Curries";
    },
    {
        "category_number" = 3;
        description = "Traditional starters";
        name = Starters;
    }
)
```

Comment: How is it possible to append a string to an array of type  catagoryModel???

Comment: I've deleted that. Wasn't originally meant to post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to Alamofire Documentation [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling).
As it suggests,

```
var categories = [categoryModel]()

Alamofire.request("http://my.custom.api.url", encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
     if let json = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
         categories = json.compactMap({ return categoryModel(name: $0["name"], description: $0["description"]) })
     }
}
```

Also, I would recommend using `CategoryModel` instead of `categoryModel` i.e. CamelCase for class names.

Answer (score 0):

Your json object has multiple errors and I will assume that you have a top level json array with key name "arr". Within the array, each object has three keys. So you will write:

```
let topLvlArray = json["arr"] as! [Any]

for obj in topLvlArray as! [String:Any] {
    let category = obj.category_number
    let description = obj.description 
    let name = obj.name
    //construct your categoryModel object
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all write a function for get json data

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      getJsonData()
}
var categories = [categoryModel]()

func getJsonData(){
Alamofire.request("http://my.custom.api.url", encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            //print(response)

            if let json = response.result.value {
             let name = json["name"].stringvalue
             let description = json["description"].stringvalue
             let dataAll = categoryModel(name: name!, description: description!)
             categories.append(dataAll)
             print(categories.count)

            }


    }
}
```